# TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tnsnames

I have oracle 11.2.0 installed on server. Everything was fine till monday.
Now i can't connect to DB by client, SQL Developer, SQL Plus.

**lsnrctl status** on server:

```
C:\Users\User1>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 14-JAN-2016 09:21
:14

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT=1
521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                13-JAN-2016 21:36:13
Uptime                    0 days 11 hr. 48 min. 19 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         c:\app\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\SERVERNAME\listener\
alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "LAND3XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "land3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "TEST3XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "test3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "TESTT10XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testt10", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "TESTXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "test", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "TEST_T10" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testt10", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "land3" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "land3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "test" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "test", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "test3" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "test3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

**tnsping DB:**

```
C:\Users\USER1>tnsping TEST3

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 14-JAN-2
016 09:25:55

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (S
ERVICE_NAME = TEST3)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

**LISTENER.ORA**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator
```

**SQLNET.ORA**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
TEST3 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TEST3)
    )
  )

TEST_T10 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TEST_T10)
    )
  )

TEST3_X64 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TEST3)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LAND3 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = LAND3)
    )
  )

TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TEST)
    )
  )
```

In logs C:\app\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\SERVERNAME\listener\alert:

```
<msg time='2016-01-14T09:21:53.324+03:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='SERVERNAME'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>14-JAN-2016 09:21:53 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=SERVERNAME$))(SERVICE_NAME=TESTLD.DOMAIN)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.29.17.141)(PORT=62670)) * establish * TESTLD.DOMAIN * 12571
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2016-01-14T09:22:03.324+03:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='SERVERNAME'
 host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>TNS-12571: TNS:packet writer failure
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
   64-bit Windows Error: 54: Unknown error
    TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
 </txt>
</msg>
```

All services are srarted.
i don't have any ides what's wrong with this.

Comment: Hi, is listener.log is greater than 4GB in size?

Comment: Hi, in C:\app\Administrator\diag\tnslsnr\SERVERNAME\listener\trace size of listener.log is 4,00 GB (4 294 967 316 bytes).

Comment: You have to empty this file.... then the listener will start working again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

> 1. Check hostname status from OS.
> 2. Check your firewall and windows 64 is not forbidding port access.

Comment: 1. Hostname in files is correct:

Windows IP Configuration

       Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVERNAME
       Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : DOMAIN
       Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
       IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
       WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
       DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : DOMAIN

2. I cheked firewall. It's OK. I also tried to make Inbound and Outbound rules for TCP 1521: Allow the connection. Nothing changed.

Comment: Now do followings ... 1. Check if user has permission of read and write on the directories where listener.log resides. 2. Check if listener.log is >4GB. because If the listener.log is greater than 4GB in size, the listener may fail to start on Windows platforms.

Comment: <  listener.log is >4GB - problem was in this file. After deleting it and restarting tnslistener everything was ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong with this setup - for instance where is your listener SID/SERVICE_NAME definition for test3 in the listener.ora? Anyway you can get away without a specific listener definition under windows.

However I think your problem is quite simple to solve, the clue is here:

```
Service "test3" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "test3", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

Your tnsnames.ora is looking for a service name of TEST3

```
TEST3 =
 (DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SERVERNAME.DOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
  )
  (CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = TEST3)
)
)
```

replace

> (SERVICE_NAME = TEST3)

with

```
(SID = test3)
```

Comment: @Ron: TEST3XDB is for xml database pourpose.... The default service name is the same as the global database name so in the most case is the same of the oracle sid

Comment: It doesn't matter, TEST3XDB points to the same instance SID test3. Both service names will work but I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: I know but it is not a good practice using *XDB to connect to database.

Comment: Agreed, sorry but I didn't scroll right down to see all the other sid/service names in the listing.  The real issue here is that the listener.ora should specifically list all the SID/SERVICE_NAMES you want tnslsnr to be listening for. It is bad practice to rely on the listener to pick all the instances in memory. One other thing I forgot to mention is that SIDs are usually case sensitive in most platforms so I've edited the tnsnames.ora to reflect this.